# How to set path to partials in Node.js with Express, Handlebars and Conslidate

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, handlebars.js

I have a working Node.js site, using Express.js, Handlebars.js and Consolidate.js. I want to use partials for common parts of my templates, but can't work out how to make them work for pages at different URLs.

My `/views/` directory contains this:

```
_footer.html
_header.html
article.html
index.html
```

The relevant parts of my Node app looks something like:

```
var express = require('express'),
    consolidate = require('consolidate'),
    handlebars = require('handlebars'),
    path = require('path');
var app = express();
app.engine('html', consolidate.handlebars);
app.set('view engine', 'html');
app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, '/views'));

var partials = {header: '_header', footer: '_footer'};

app.get('/', function(req, res) {
    res.render('index', {partials: partials});
};
app.get(/^\/([\w-]+)\/$/, function(req, res) {
    res.render('article', {partials: partials});
};
```

And in my `index.html` and `article.html` Handlebars templates I have something like:

```
{{> header}}
<!-- page content here -->
{{> footer }}
```

I should be able to access both `/` (when `index.html` is rendered) and `/foo/` (when `article.html` is rendered). But it only works for whichever I try to access first after starting the Node server. When I then navigate to the other path, I get errors like:

```
Error: ENOENT, no such file or directory '/Users/phil/Projects/projectname/views/<!DOCTYPE html>...
```

with the rest of the `_header.html` partial following.

I assume I need to somehow set the path to my partials to be absolute somehow, but I can't see how to do that.

Answer (score 0):

For consolidate check that : https://github.com/tj/consolidate.js/issues/18

I would recommend to switch to something a bit more specific like that https://github.com/donpark/hbs it will be simpler.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same exact issue. It seems that consolidate [is reusing the "partials" object that you pass](https://github.com/tj/consolidate.js/blob/master/lib/consolidate.js#L115), replacing the values with the file content (yuck!). 
A workaround is to create a new "partials" object every time. If you don't want to rewrite the whole object every time, you can use a function returning the object literal.
In your case something like the following should work:

```
var express = require('express'),
    consolidate = require('consolidate'),
    handlebars = require('handlebars'),
    path = require('path');
var app = express();
app.engine('html', consolidate.handlebars);
app.set('view engine', 'html');
app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, '/views'));

var partials = function() {
    return {header: '_header', footer: '_footer'};
}

app.get('/', function(req, res) {
    res.render('index', {partials: partials()});
};
app.get(/^\/([\w-]+)\/$/, function(req, res) {
    res.render('article', {partials: partials()});
};
```

Not really elegant, but I don't think there is really a way to keep it simpler.